# vba issues with copy and PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the content of a entire row copied automatically from one sheet to another whenever there is an update in a specific column of the source sheet. i encountered two issues with my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("K:K")
 If Intersect(target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Dim c As Range
 If target = "Completed" Then
 target.EntireRow.Copy 'paste special works now, thanks BigBen
 Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 End If
End Sub
```

1. The code doesn't copies when the column K in the source sheet is updated using a formula. It only works when the text "Completed" is updated manually.
2. When the row is copied it copies the formula instead of Text, only the text from the source sheet needs to be copied. I've been trying to use **.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues** but there is a compile error - Expected End of Statement.

This is the last part of my project which retrieves the all the files generated in a day, renames it based on certain parameters and clears the sheet. This copy function would be a log of all successful renames done. I am stuck here because the of this copy paste issue.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` doesn't work when a formula is recalculated. You need `Worksheet_Calculate` for that.

Comment: If you're using `PasteSpecial`, it has to be two lines.... copy in the first line, pastespecial in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ben, i tried copy paste in separate lines, but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: `Target.EntireRow.Copy`... then `Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` in a different line. Or you can use value transfer and skip the clipboard altogether.

Comment: It worked Ben. thanks..  Also i tried changing from Change to Calculate i am getting error when every formula updates

Comment: What's your revised code? Can you [edit] your question?

Comment: I have updated the new code.

Comment: `If target = "Completed" Then` - you have to loop through each cell, or use `Range.AutoFilter`. You can't compare an entire column to the text "Completed"

Comment: Ok.. I'll try that.

Comment: `Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim r, lr7 As Long, target As Range
    Set target = Range("K:K")
    lr7 = Sheets("Reflect").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 If Intersect(target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
r = 1
 Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Reflect").Cells(r, 1))
 If (Sheets("Reflect").Cells(r, 11)) = "Completed" Then
 target.EntireRow.Copy
 Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 r = r + 1
 If r = lr7 Then Exit Sub
    End If
 Loop
 End Sub `  i tried this, doesnt work